# Change HTML Document Title On Localhost but not Server

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to change the title of a page based on the URL query params.
It works on localhost but not server.
I used the following hooks and all not working on server

`wp_title`

`‎document_title_parts‎`

`pre_get_document_title`

I used `print_r` to check the function work in its different steps and it works well on server, However, the document title doesn't change

---

An example using`document_title_parts`

```
function change_page_title($title)
{
    if ($GLOBALS["pagename"]) === "my-page") {
        $title['title'] = "new title";
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('document_title_parts', 'change_page_title');
```

---

**Update**
When I change the theme to "Twenty Twenty Three" on the server it works, so I guess there is something in my current theme that prevents the hook job